# The grid system of the brochure for Die Neue Typographie

Tags: typography, grids

This is page 35 from the book Grid Systems: Principles of Organizing Type. In this page author give us an example of the brochure for Die Neue Typographie.
I can't understand how this grid system comes out? They mentioned there are two same width column overlapped and they have created a narrower column, but I can't see how they overlap, the overlay didn't show it.
[image: the content at this page]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly: it looks like there is a basic two column set up as indicated at the very bottom ("column width").

Then to set up the left column, the designer "stole" 1/3 of the right column, and of that one third, used 1/3 for the gutter. This left 2/3 of a column for the upper right, and the bottom right is the original column width.

The designer may have used a geometric series as an inspiration, or simply liked thirds. The scan is not perfect, nor squared off, so getting precise measurements is not possible without the original.